# Get language fails

Tags: android

I'm using **Locale** class for obtain language code and it returns **und** in api version 23 but api 8 and 14 it works.

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();//returns und
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns **und** because I needed to set a locale configuration for the device example: Menu>Custom Locale>choose any

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();` instead of `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();`.

Hope this helped.